# Decode JSON array without keys in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, decode, codable

I make a request to the [OpenSky Network API](https://opensky-network.org/apidoc/rest.html) and get a result like this:

```
{
  "time":1629739170,
  "states":[
    ["4b1800","SWR1076 ","Switzerland",1629739169,1629739169,8.5493,47.4581,373.38,false,79.14,275.97,7.15,null,487.68,null,false,0],
    ["3c65c4","DLH35A  ","Germany",1629739170,1629739170,6.5185,46.2346,11590.02,false,255.57,48.84,0,null,11986.26,"1000",false,0]
  ]
}
```

Now I want to decode that JSON string to a list of `FlightState` objects, but there are no keys provided. From the API documentation (see link above) I know what value corresponds to what property, but how do I create corresponding Swift objects?

The following doesn't work, obviously, because there are no keys.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()             
let flightState: FlightState = try! decoder.decode(FlightState.self, from: dataString.data(using: .utf8)!)


struct FlightState: Codable {
    
    let time: Int
    let states: [StateVector]

    struct StateVector: Codable {
        let icao24: UUID
        let callsign: String
        let origin_country: String
        let time_position: Int
        let last_contact: Int
        let longitude: Float
        let latitude: Float
        let baro_altitude: Float
        let on_ground: Bool
        let velocity: Float
        let true_track: Float
        let vertical_rate: Float
        let sensors: [Int]
        let geo_altitude: Float
        let squawk: String
        let spi: Bool
        let position_source: Int
    }

}
```

The error message says `Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.` So how do I tell Swift to interpret the values in the `states` lists as properties of objects with their corresponding type?

I have the feeling that someone must have been stumbled upon this before, but I couldn't find a solution. Maybe I am too new to Swift to recognize a solution as such.

Comment: "let icao24: UUID"  UUID?  Where does it come from?

Comment: @ElTomato I know that it is described as `string` in the API documentation, but I thought a uuid is required to an object in Swift!? For this property corresponds to the "Unique ICAO 24-bit address of the transponder" I thought I could simply use `UUID` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decode a JSON where specific properties are held in specific array indices rather than under specific `Dictionary` keys by implementing `init(from decoder:)` on your own and using an `unkeyedContainer()` to decode the array, then calling `decode` to decode each property in order.

Bear in mind lots of properties in the response can be `null`, so you need to declare those as `Optional` and use `decodeIfPresent` rather than `decode`.

```
struct FlightState: Decodable {

    let time: Int
    let states: [StateVector]

    struct StateVector: Decodable {
        let icao24: String
        let callSign: String
        let originCountry: String
        let timePosition: Int?
        let lastContact: Int
        let longitude: Float?
        let latitude: Float?
        let baroAltitude: Float?
        let onGround: Bool
        let velocity: Float?
        let trueTrack: Float?
        let verticalRate: Float?
        let sensors: [Int]?
        let geoAltitude: Float?
        let squawk: String?
        let spi: Bool
        let positionSource: Int

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            var values = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
            self.icao24 = try values.decode(String.self)
            self.callSign = try values.decode(String.self)
            self.originCountry = try values.decode(String.self)
            self.timePosition = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self)
            self.lastContact = try values.decode(Int.self)
            self.longitude = try values.decodeIfPresent(Float.self)
            self.latitude = try values.decodeIfPresent(Float.self)
            self.baroAltitude = try values.decodeIfPresent(Float.self)
            self.onGround = try values.decode(Bool.self)
            self.velocity = try values.decodeIfPresent(Float.self)
            self.trueTrack = try values.decodeIfPresent(Float.self)
            self.verticalRate = try values.decodeIfPresent(Float.self)
            self.sensors = try values.decodeIfPresent([Int].self)
            self.geoAltitude = try values.decodeIfPresent(Float.self)
            self.squawk = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self)
            self.spi = try values.decode(Bool.self)
            self.positionSource = try values.decode(Int.self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you!